# Adding a JAVA project to an SVN repo using subclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

So I already created my project and been working on it for a while. I now created an SVN repository and want to check in all my work so far there and continue from there. However, I couldn't manage to do this using sublicpse. Any ideas ?

EDIT: I am basically trying to add an already existing java project in my workspace to my SVN repo without using the command line functions like "svn add" or things like copy paste. Is it possible to link my already existing project to an SVN repo by right clicking or something like that ? Thats kind of what I am wondering

Comment: "I couldn't manage to do this using subclipse". All I can deduce from that sentence is that you failed at something. Try again or give us more details. A lot more.

Comment: Isn't it just a matter of copying the files to the WC and then adding them and committing? (Btw, I *highly* recommend using Hg or Git or similar. Once you use a decent [D]VCS you'll likely *never willingly* go back to SVN ;-)

Comment: I am basically trying to add an already existing java project in my workspace to my SVN repo without using the command line functions like "svn add" or things like copy paste. Is it possible to link my already existing project to an SVN repo by right clicking or something like that ? Thats kind of what I am wondering

Comment: What's wrong with the command line?

Comment: Your edit _helps_ clarify your intent, but it doesn't help us understand what you tried or why it failed.

Comment: I guess its a bit hard to explain so I will see what I can do to find out what I need but thanks for the help though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you've created a location in the repository for your project, you can right click on your Eclipse project and choose `Team -> Share Project`. You'll likely have to "Create a new repository location" first, then complete the wizard.

Comment: Thanks you were actually the only one who understood what's going on and helped me. This was exactly what I needed. Thanks again.